# Get all objects which contains any given array of Enums

Tags: java, performance

**What this does?:**

`Interactions` is an Enum whereas `Interactable` is an interface (not @Functional Interface). Every `Interactable` has a list of `Interactions` that it can do. The below code snippet, filters out all the objects that contains any of the provided `Interactions`. It does not check for all `Interactions`, so if any of the given `Interactions` found, it adds the object in `interactableList`. Once done iterative over the `List`, sends it back to the caller for further processing.

```
public List<Interactable> getObjectsByInteractions (final Interactions[] interactions) {
    final List<Interactable> interactableList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Interactable object : objects) {
        List<Interactions> objectInteractions = object.getInteractions();
        for (Interactions interactions1 : interactions) {
            if (objectInteractions.contains(interactions1)) {
                interactableList.add(object);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return interactableList;
}
```

**Concern:**

Right now, I am using pre Java 8 code style to achieve the results. Since, it's the time of Java 8, I would request the reviewers to suggest Java 8 style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing particularly wrong with your current code, although I have a couple of comments:

- The name `interactions1` of the local variable is slightly confusing.
- Instead of having a `break`, you could have a separate method that determines if a given `Interactable` contains as interactions one of the given interactions.

With the Stream API, you could have the following:

```
public List<Interactable> getObjectsByInteractions(final Interactions[] interactions) {
    return objects.stream()
                  .filter(object -> Arrays.stream(interactions).anyMatch(object.getInteractions()::contains))
                  .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This creates a `Stream<Interactable>` of your objects. It then filters out all the unwanted object: for that a `Stream<Interactions>` of the given interactions is created and [`anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) tells whether `object.getInteractions()` contains one of those interactions. Finally, the elements are collected into a list.

Comment: Note: If `objects` is an `Interactable[]` instead of a `Iterable<? extends Interactable>`, you should use `Arrays.stream(objects)` instead of `objects.stream()`

Comment: objects is an `List<Interactable>` which is `Iterable<? extends Interactable>`. But thanks for the input though.